# stream webcam + record Nodejs

Tags: node.js, record, gpio

Доброго времени суток,
иметься датчик движения, подключенный к raspberry pi gpio. Через Nodejs научился управлять датчиком. Также имеется webcamera usb, подключенная к raspberry pi.
Задача такова, когда есть движения, датчик отправляет программе 1, и в этот момент я б хотел бы включить запись с web-камеры. Нет движения (0) - обратное действие.
Так можно такое сделать в Nodejs ?

Comment: что-то подобное нашел, но не знаю можно ли его использовать /dev/video ?
https://github.com/troyth/node-raspicam

Answer (score 0):

За Nodejs подсказать к сожалению не могу, скорее всего врядли, ибо я так понял датчик аппаратный и нужен доступ к пинам.
Тем не менее, у вас очень типовая задача. Стоит поискать по теме видеонаблюдение. В оболочках сама камера может отслеживать движения и делать запись по нему.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос